# How to Access Link Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I just implemented the many to many relationship between two models, Manga and Genre through entity framework core 6.0 which created the link table GenreManga in my database. I am trying to access all genres that are related to a specific manga, but I am stuck on trying to access the link table. My solution follows the repository structure and unit of work pattern.

The stackoverflow answers on this similar question lead me to this format:

```
var genres = _unitOfWork.GenreMangas.Include(a => a.Genres);
```

However, I can't access the link table like other stackoverflow users and I get this error:

> 'IUnitOfWork' does not contain a definition for 'GenreMangas' and no accessible extension method 'GenreMangas' accepting a first argument of type 'IUnitOfWork' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Maybe I need to change how I define and use some things? I'm not even sure where to begin. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Below is a lot of my classes, but I hope it explains the structure (or disorganization).

```
public class Manga
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int Chapters { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
        [Range(1,5)]
        public double Rating { get; set; }
        public int Views { get; set; }
        [ValidateNever]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Genre>? Genres { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Author")]
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        [ValidateNever]
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Genre
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Manga>? Mangas { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class MangaVM
    {
        public Manga Manga { get; set; }
        [ValidateNever]
        public List<Genre>? Genres { get; set; }
        [ValidateNever]
        public List<string> GenresList { get; set; }
        [ValidateNever]
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AuthorList { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Manga> Mangas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            Genre = new GenreRepository(_dbContext);
            Author = new AuthorRepository(_dbContext);
            Manga = new MangaRepository(_dbContext);
            Page = new PageRepository(_dbContext);
            Chapter = new ChapterRepository(_dbContext);
        }
        public IGenreRepository Genre { get; private set; }
        public IAuthorRepository Author { get; private set; }

        public IMangaRepository Manga { get; private set; }
        public IPageRepository Page { get; private set; }
        public IChapterRepository Chapter { get; private set; }
        public void Save()
        {
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IGenreRepository Genre { get; }
        IAuthorRepository Author { get; }
        IMangaRepository Manga { get; }
        IPageRepository Page { get; }
        IChapterRepository Chapter { get; }
        void Save();
    }
```

```
public class MangaRepository : Repository<Manga>, IMangaRepository
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

        public MangaRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;

        }

        public void Update(Manga obj)
        {
            var objFromDb = _dbContext.Mangas.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == obj.Id);
            if (objFromDb != null)
            {
                objFromDb.Title = obj.Title;
                objFromDb.Description = obj.Description;
                objFromDb.Status = obj.Status;
                objFromDb.Chapters = obj.Chapters;
                objFromDb.Updated = obj.Updated;
                objFromDb.Rating = obj.Rating;
                objFromDb.Views = obj.Views;
                objFromDb.AuthorId = obj.AuthorId;
                if (obj.ImageUrl != null)
                {
                    objFromDb.ImageUrl = obj.ImageUrl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public interface IMangaRepository : IRepository<Manga>
    {
        void Update(Manga obj);
    }
```

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;
        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            //_dbContext.Mangas.Include(a => a.Genre).Include(a=>a.Author);
            this.dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
        }
        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }
        //includeProp - "Genre,Author"
        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string? includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
            if(includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach(var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProp);
                }
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetDataFromDbSetUsingFk(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, string? includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
            query = query.Where(filter);
            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach (var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProp);
                }
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }

        public T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, string? includeProperties = null)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
            query = query.Where(filter);
            if (includeProperties != null)
            {
                foreach(var includeProp in includeProperties.Split(new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    query = query.Include(includeProp);
                }
            }
            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity)
        {
            dbSet.RemoveRange(entity);
        }
    }
```

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        //T - Genre
        T GetFirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, string? includeProperties = null);
        IEnumerable<T> GetDataFromDbSetUsingFk(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, string? includeProperties = null);
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll(string? includeProperties = null);
        void Add(T entity);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity);
    }
```

[Solution Explorer Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSF4E.png)

[DB Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4eMf.png)

EDIT: Tried using this code as suggested and appears to work but genres is null even though there are two records in genremanga table for the for that manga Id. I still feel like it is not accessing the link table at all.

```
var mangaGenres = _unitOfWork.Manga.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == id).SelectMany(a => a.Genres);
```

[MangaObj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSW7k.jpg)

[GenreManga Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yyYv.png)

Answer (score 0):

Without superfluous abstraction it is easy:

```cs
var genres = await _context.Manga
    .Where(m => m.Id == mangaId)
    .SelectMany(m => m.Genres)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Remember that `DbContext` is already Unit of Work and `DbSet` is already repository,

Comment: I used this
`var mangaGenres = _unitOfWork.Manga.GetAll().Where(a => a.Id == id).SelectMany(a => a.Genres);`

But genres is null even though there are two records in the genremanga database for that manga.

Comment: Because you are fighting with you abstraction.` GetAll()` should return `IQueryable`. Or you have to `Include` genres.

Comment: I tried using `Include()` but error came up that Manga does not contain a definition and I'm not sure that one should be defined... I made a separate method Get() to return `IQueryable` but I realized that is most likely not the issue. I'm assuming (not sure) due to `public ICollection<Genre>? Genres { get; set; }` in my manga model, `SelectMany(a => a.Genres)`, Genres will always be null.